# Undefined error when importing .jpx file to Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle eBusiness suite running at my company. I've extended a view object based on code from the [Oracle Applications Hack](http://oracle-hack.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-extend-view-object-in-oa.html).

I've compiled my objects, but when I try running the command line script to import my .jpx file for my substitution, it throws an "Undefined Error." Has anyone seen this and worked around it?

My import command:

```
C:\jdeveloper\jdevbin\oaext\bin\jpximport C:\jdeveloper\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses\ORAR12DEV.jpx -username username -password password -dbconnection "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mydb.mycompany.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(DEV)))"
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error you are getting?

Comment: That's the problem - the error is *Undefined Error*. (Helpful, isn't it?)

Comment: Did you make sure that the `substitution command` exists in the `.jpx`?

Comment: Yes, the substitution command is there. The error thrown says "Database error" - followed by my connection string - then "Unspecified Error." I'm trying to upload from my machine to a remote database, if that makes a difference. I've read there's a way to import on the server as well - anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you try this format using the jpximport.bat file as `jpximport.bat D:\xxxxx\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses\xxxxxx.jpx -username user -password pwd -dbconnection "(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=yourhost.oracle.com)(port=xxxx))) (connect_data=(sid=DEV)))"`

Comment: That's exactly how I called the command (except for the settings specific to my DB, of course).

Comment: Then, can you update the import command in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing keyword `SID` (assuming `DEV` is your `SID`). Like below

```
(CONNECT_DATA=(DEV))
```

Corrected command

```
C:\jdeveloper\jdevbin\oaext\bin\jpximport C:\jdeveloper\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses\ORAR12DEV.jpx -username username -password password -dbconnection "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mydb.mycompany.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEV)))"
```